# Components of a bounded vector must be bounded

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with basis $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$.

Let $c = (c_1, \dots, c_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose $\| c_1 x_1 + \dots + c_n x_n \| = 1$.
I'm trying to show that $\| c \| < M$ for some $M$.

I feel like this should be extremely straight-forward, but I don't know how to show it. I've considered the map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $(c_1, \dots, c_n) \mapsto \| c_1 x_1 + \dots + c_n x_n \|$ and shown that this is continuous. If I could also say that the pre-image of $\{1\}$ is compact, I would have the boundedness, but this is not true in general for continuous maps.

Comment: Since you're using norm I assume you can also use inner product and even orthonormal basis, right?

Comment: I'm familiar with orthonormal bases, but we haven't explicitly discussed them. I think it should be able to be done without assuming/taking an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Start at the other end, look at $S = \{ c \in \mathbb{R}^n : \lVert c\rVert = 1\}$. What can you say about $f(S)$?

Comment: This should be straight forward if you do a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Your function f is a norm. Now, note that all norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent.

Comment: since $\|c\|=\| c_1 x_1 + \dots + c_n x_n \| = 1$, i really don't get the question.